# Chatrooms about mathematics?

Tags: discussion, chat

How is http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/482/a-room-with-a-view-on-music-bird-names happens to be on the "list of rooms about mathematics" on the chat.SE page?

Is there a way to remove it from there, or at least from the main/meta sidebar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The room was created by a user whose main account (as for being linked to the chat account) is on math.SE, and they didn't change the site to which the room belongs (it defaults to the user's main site).

But since the user themselves asked for the room to be deleted, I have done so, and thus it has disappeared now.

Comment: Much obliged :-)